# Не обновляется wordpress

Tags: wordpress, update

У меня сейчас версия 4.6.3. Всегда он обновлялся автоматически без проблем. Сегодня я его решил обновить и получил сообщение:

```
Downloading update from .../wordpress-4.7.2-new-bundled.zip…
Unpacking the update…
Verifying the unpacked files…
The update could not be unpacked
Installation Failed
```

Я по инструкции пробовал обновиться вручную, но при этом использовав файл "no-content", чтобы просто заменить старое на новое. В этом случае вход совершается, БД обновляется но сама админка отображается "без стилей" - списком.

У меня директория upgrade - пуста с правами 777
на другие файлы папки 755.

Я конечно хочу решить этот вопрос автоматическим образом. Подскажите, что необходимо сделать для этого?

Answer (score 0):

> Я по инструкции пробовал обновиться вручную, но при этом использовав файл "no-content",

Это какие-то левые инструкции - нет такого файла в ВП.. И судя по имени закачиваемого файла используется какая-то левая сборка.

Как правильно перейти на оф. ВП см [тут](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_WordPress_Lecactus_Edition):

2 варианта:

1. Установить плагин [Restore Automatic Update](http://wordpress.org/plugins/restore-automatic-update/), затем воспользоваться штатным автоматическим обновлением. После обновления плагин можно удалить.
2. [Скачать архив новой версии](http://ru.wordpress.org/releases/) и обновить вручную через FTP.

И про бекапы не забываем.

Comment: 1) Первый плагин не повлиял на обновление.
2) Архив скачал, и сообщаю как обновлял вручную: удалил 2 директории как указано "wp-admin" и "wp-includes". Далее загрузил на сервер разархивированные директории "wp-admin" и "wp-includes" только уже новые. Далее "заменил" все файлы в корне. Всем папкам присвоил 755. После этого снова-же сайт отображается корректно, а админка без "стилей". Хотя хром пишет что не подключен jQury... Может в этом причина, а может в правах каки-то... вроде всё делаю как написано...

Comment: Где указано про " 2 директории"? В инструкции об этом ни слова. Зато сказано про отключение плагинов. А вот о чём не сказано, а надо бы - так это о переключении на родную тему и удаление всех кешей и их следов.

Comment: Официальное обновление по ссылке: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_WordPress где всё расписано по пунктам. Я выполняю всё по порядку: 1) оключаю все плагины. 2) скачал новый ВП 3) как указано удалил все файлы с директорий "wp-admin" и "wp-includes". 4) скопировал новые файлы в корень с заменой. Суть в том, что сайр работает! всё ок! вот только админка без стилей как список отображается... Вы думаете, что если я перед копированием тему поменяю на дефолтную, то всё будет правильно? я просто не понимаю как тема сайта влияет на админку ВП.

Comment: В этой инструкции  ещё и про кеш написано и про темы. Но надо понимать, что этой инструкции много лет и указанных там тем давно не существует. Как не существует и некоторых файлов в корне.  Но есть другие, которые надо залить из дистра. А при проблемах - тему нужно сменить на дефолтную. И вообще инструкция по поиску виновного в [пп 3-6,8](https://codex.wordpress.org/Как_задавать_правильные_вопросы). А темы и плагины должны быть только из оф каталога и актуальные, а не с древним последним обновлением.

Comment: Оказывается в моём случае единственное правильное решение это обновление **vsftpd** - инструкция по ссылке: http://insanepengu.in/wordpress-update-could-not-be-unpacked-fix-on-debian-vsftpd-3-0-2/